# How to add existent options inside product options

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, programmatically, simple-product, attribute-options

I trying to add simple products and after associate these products in a configurable product, but some options of these products can't be exists.

So, I add options using EVA config and return id of options, but these options have type like

> Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface

And

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->addOptions()

or

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->addOption()

requires object type like

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option

I don't understand how Magento can create options like this. See that they already exist inside objects like

> Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute

I needed to associate my products with these options but I don't understand how I can do it.

Suppose the method works perfectly for the purpose of inserting options into the attributes and the option objects are returned from this call. Follow the code.

```
$options = $this->helper->setupAttributeOptions([
    "size" => $configurable["options"]["size"],
    "color" => $configurable["options"]["color"],
]);
/*
return ->
[
    "color" => [
        0 => [
            "label" => "Red",
            "option_object" => Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface 
        ] 
    ],
    "size" => [
        0 => [
            "label" => 40,
            "option_object" => Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface 
        ] 
    ]
]
*/
```

I parse result and extract `option_object` inside an other simple array. Load my simple product by SKU using `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` and add options with this.

```
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$product->setOptions($correctOptions);
$product->save();
```

I try using `$productRepository->save($product);` but not have success.

Any idea.